# Customize the notification options in iOS 10

Tags: ios, notifications, ios10

Notifications in iOS 9, we can customize the notification actions in the Notification tray using (UIUserNotificationActionContext.Minimal). This API is deprecated in iOS 10.

[image]

Now, in iOS 10, I see the notification actions as "View" and "Clear". Is there any way to change these default actions to like something like snooze, delete, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Categories for that so that you can customize your own actions. Refer to [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SupportingNotificationsinYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH4-SW26)

Some sample code -

```
UNNotificationAction* stopAction = [UNNotificationAction
  actionWithIdentifier:@"STOP_ACTION"
  title:@"Stop"
  options:UNNotificationActionOptionForeground];

// Create the category with the custom actions.
UNNotificationCategory* expiredCategory = [UNNotificationCategory
  categoryWithIdentifier:@"TIMER_EXPIRED"
  actions:@[stopAction]
  intentIdentifiers:@[]
  options:UNNotificationCategoryOptionNone];
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but I want the Actions in the Notification bar (when swiped to left). Currently it only shows "View" or "Clear" (my question  is whether we can customize these 2 options or not?).